# binding output to a readonly textinput

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and python, though i was trying to create an app where i can communicate with my device 'like chatting ' but i had trouble binding the response for the computer to a read only text input...so far the response go to python shell...please help me find a solution!!

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty,StringProperty

from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

import random

class Trial(RelativeLayout):

    def text(self,val):

        writing = StringProperty('')

        self.writing = val

        if val in ['hi','hey','whatsup','sup','good morning']:

            d = random.choice (['hey','hi','good morning','sup'])

            print(d)

        else:

            print('Nope')





class project_2(App):

    def build(self):

        return Trial()

if __name__=="__main__":

    project_2().run()
```

### kv file

```
<Trial>:

    TextInput:
        id:txt_inpt
        size_hint: [None,None]
        width:500
        height:50
        pos_hint:{'left':1,'top':0.9}
    TextInput:
        id:inpt
        size_hint: [None,None]
        width:500
        height:50
        pos_hint:{'right':1,'top':0.8}

    Button:
        text:'send'
        size_hint: [None,None]
        width:50
        height:50
        pos_hint:{'left':1,'top':1}
        on_release:root.text(txt_inpt.text)
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand your question, I think you can just replace `print` statements with `self.ids.inpt.text=d` or `self.ids.inpt.text='Nope'`.

Comment: Try using `disabled: True` in the kv file for your text input